# How can I get parent with all children in one query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following mapping:

```
PUT /test_products
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "entity_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "weighted": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
        "product_relation": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "window": "simple"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get "window" products with all "simple"s but only where one or more "simple"s have property "weighted" = 1

I wrote following query:

```
GET test_products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "simple",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "weighted": 1
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

But I've got "window"s with "simple"s which are match to the term. In other words I want to filter "window"s list by "simple"'s option and get all matched "window"s with all their "simple"s. Is it possible without "nested" in one query? Or I have to do some queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Luckily, I need to get only one "window" product with all it's children by it's ID, so I found [parent_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-parent-id-query.html) query which can helps me with this task.

Now I have following query:

```
GET test_products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "parent_id": {
      "type": "simple",
      "id": "window-1"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to execute 2 queries (`has_child` and then `parent_id`) instead of one but it's OK for me.